# SonarQube: No information about coverage per test, surefire reports and jacoco

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco, sonar-runner, maven-surefire-plugin

I checked almost all similar issues to my question and tried to test them for two days. So, I am asking here: 
I am using: SonarQube server 5.6.6 and SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778.
the sonar.properties have been set based on this example project: [combined-ut-it-sonar-runner-jacoco](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/projects/languages/java/code-coverage/combined%20ut-it/combined-ut-it-sonar-runner-jacoco/sonar-project.properties)

For more clarification please check the analysis parameters that I have set for this project:

```
sonar.sources=src/main/java
sonar.tests=src/test/java
sonar.java.binaries=target/classes
sonar.java.test.binaries=target/test-classes

sonar.jacoco.reportPath=target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec
sonar.jacoco.itReportPath=target/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec
sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports
```

Log info that I receive:(I put related logs to my parameters here)

```
INFO: Source paths: src/main/java
INFO: Test paths: src/test/java

INFO: Sensor SurefireSensor
INFO: parsing /home/jenkins-slave/workspace/team/project/target/surefire-reports
INFO: Sensor SurefireSensor (done) | time=382ms
INFO: Sensor JaCoCoSensor
INFO: Analysing /home/jenkins-slave/workspace/team/project/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec
INFO: No information about coverage per test.

INFO: Sensor JaCoCoSensor (done) | time=602ms
INFO: Sensor JaCoCoItSensor
INFO: Analysing /home/jenkins-slave/workspace/team/project/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec
INFO: No information about coverage per test. 

INFO: Sensor JaCoCoItSensor (done) | time=326ms
INFO: Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor
INFO: Analysing /home/jenkins-slave/workspace/team/project/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec
INFO: Analysing /home/jenkins-slave/workspace/team/project/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec
INFO: Analysing /home/jenkins-slave/workspace/team/project/.scannerwork/jacoco-overall.exec
INFO: No information about coverage per test.
INFO: Sensor JaCoCoOverallSensor (done) | time=348ms
```

Now in the sonarQube, I can see separate results for integration coverage and unit test coverage:
[image]

But no details information such as coverage by which unit test. I would like ideally to have information like: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Seeing+Tests

Now my questions are: since I already pointed surefire reports(a folder that contains surefire xml files reports) correctly as well as jacoco reports, how can I get information about coverage per test? Am I missing something here? I am a little bit confused because I do not know the exact difference between sonar.junit.reportsPath and sonar.surefire.reportsPath? I do not understand completely which one is responsible to provide information for coverage per test: surefire reports or jacoco reports? Based on the log files, it seems that jacoco is responsible for that. Then, what is the surefire reports role in this analysis?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You do realize that the docs page you pointed to shows those details not from a code file but from a test file, right? Also, you appear to be using Maven to build, so you should be using Maven to analyze too: `mvn clean install sonar:sonar`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sonarqube: view unit tests that cover the source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37662649/sonarqube-view-unit-tests-that-cover-the-source)